# Анализ данных после парсинга

Tags: java, android, парсер, android-service

Есть приложение, которое парсит сайт. Как сделать так, чтобы сравнить полученные данные с эталонными (при помощи `if` или т.п), а если эти данные совпадут, то вывести уведомление.

Т.е, допустим, я хочу сравнить минуты с часов с главной страницы Яндекса. Когда минуты становятся равными `55`, то пользователю приходит уведомление об этом.

P.S минуты я взял условно, чтобы показать, что данные постоянно меняются.

Comment: В чем у вас проблема? Вы же сами написали что будете использовать if? 
Вы не можете сравнить if(minute.equals("55")) если это String, или if(minute == 55), если int?

Comment: В Вашем случае, придется пройтись по списку с помощью цикла for: `for (var item: myList) {}`. Для того, чтобы дать более подробный или понятный ответ - рекомендую вам объяснить вашу задачу\проблему и приложить примеры кода